# Table or DataTable in Flutter with merged cells

Tags: flutter, dart, datatable

Hi I need to do something like this in Flutter but I can't do it with either datatable or table alone. Does anyone know which widget to use or any libs to achieve it easily. Regards!

[image]

Comment: Have you got a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, rowspan and colspan capabilities are not yet supported in Flutter. In fact, there is an [open bug](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21594) that focuses on this issue.

If you just need this functionality for static table, try to put a table inside a table since [TableRow](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TableRow-class.html) accepts any widget in children, achieving basically the same result.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: Table(border: TableBorder.all(), children: [
            const TableRow(children: [
              Text('Column 1'),
              Text('Column 2'),
            ]),
            TableRow(children: [
              const Text('Entry 1'),
              Table(border: TableBorder.all(), children: const [
                TableRow(children: [
                  Text('Nested Entry 1'),
                  Text('Nested Entry 2'),
                ]),
                TableRow(children: [
                  Text('Nested Entry 3'),
                  Text('Nested Entry 4'),
                ]),
              ]),
            ]),
          ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```